# Check Session for a password

Tags: php

I'm trying to store a variable of a POST request into a session, so I don't need to make the POST request each time I click somewhere on the page.
I'm getting the following errors:
Undefined index: password on line 8, 10, 12
Even if the password is right, it says that it is invalid.
Here's my code

```
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);
//@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
/* 
Checking for login
*/
if (!$_POST['pw'] == "") {
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['pw'];
}
$pass = $_SESSION['password'];
$configpassword = "a random password";
$sessionpass = $_SESSION['password'];
if (!$pass == $configpassword) {
    echo "<title>ACCESS DENIED !</title><h2>ACCESS DENIED !</h2>";
    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'login.php';\",1500);</script>";
    session_destroy();
    die();
}
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML, specially the password field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your conditionals have an issue with operator precedence.

`if (!$_POST['pw'] == "")`

This will evaluate whether `(!$_POST['pw'])` is equal to `""` which will first cast  `$_POST['pw']` to a boolean, then negate it, then compare that to the boolean value of `""` (which is false).  This will end up making your conditional do the opposite of what you want:  `!$_POST['pw'] == ""` is true only when `$_POST['pw']` is equal to `""` (or any other falsey value, like `"0"`).

Same problem with `if (!$pass == $configpassword)`

Try changing these to:

`if ($_POST['pw'] != "")`

and

`if ($pass != $configpassword)`